# NSNotification register place issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, addobserver

I have a tab bar application in which there are 2 tabs(2 view controllers). I need to post notification from tab 2(view controller 2) to tab 1(view controller 1). But the problem is that i have to necessarily first go to tab 1(view controller 1) in order to register for notification, if i dont do this the notification is never registered. It seems that view is only allocated once i select it and then move to tab 2(view controller 2) to post notification.

in register for notification in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(createYourOwnPressed:) name:@"createYourOwnPressed" object:nil];
```

So, how can i avoid first selecting tab 1(view controller 1) and then post notification from tab 2(view controller 2)?

Thanks!!

Comment: A class that handles notifications should be alive all the time. My suggest is to rely on another class like your app delegate, that handles notifications and talks with view controllers at the proper moment.

Comment: Btw are you using storyboards?

Comment: no storyboards...xib's

Answer (score 0):

If you have the instances of the view controllers in the tabs in say appDelegate you try something like this in applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:tab1viewcontroller selector:@selector(createYourOwnPressed:) name:@"createYourOwnPressed" object:nil];
```

or do this, while adding view controller to UITabBarController

```
ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:vc selector:@selector(createYourOwnPressed:) name:@"createYourOwnPressed" object:nil];
```

Comment: but the selector i cant access in appDelegate

Comment: that doesn't matter. The selector is send to the observer, so it's needs to be declared and implemented there.

Comment: you mean i have to declare and define my selector in appDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register for notifications before view loads (viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear), I'd recommend you to register when the view controller is initialized (initWithNibName, init etc), so you'll be sure that your vc instance will get notifications.

Otherwise there's a little hack to force your controller to load the view, like below:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];  
[vc view]; // force view load
```

then just insert it to your navigation controller. That way you won't have to switch to 1st tab to load the view.

Comment: i did not find any mention of the storyboards. and by the separated one you meant another observer, i guess?